# K-Method in Type II Controller

Tags: controller

Refer to [this document](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1049/iet-pel.2015.0144), K-method can be used to find the pole and zero frequency of a Type II controller. There is one point confusing me. Right before Equation 30, it said k is a ratio of fp and fz. However, Equation 30 uses fp = k * fc while fp is also equal to k*fz. That will lead to fz equal to fc, which is not correct.

Can anyone help me to clarify this?

[image]